# How to setup Rspec and Factory girl with MongoMapper

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, mongomapper

I had a vanilla rails 4 project with ActiveRecord, Rspec, and FactoryGirl.

Requirements changed and we switched to storing our data in MongoDb. We're using MongoMapper for the model mapping.

I haven't removed ActiveRecord from the project, I've simply stopped using it and removed all the ActiveRecord::Base classes (they now implement MongoMapper modules).

What do I need to do to configure Rspec + FactoryGirl so that all the FactoryGirl factories talk to MongoDb?

I'm confused about where Rspec and FactoryGirl assume the DB is.